# Automating the conversion of file formats

Tags: automation, conversion

I have a collection of folders, some of which contain .flac files while others contain .mp3 files. I need everything to be in .mp3, but I don't exactly want to go through hundreds of folders in format factory. Is there anyway to automate this process in either Windows or Linux.

Comment: Your question sounds like asking for software recommendation. Maybe you get more help at softwarerec.stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

A quick bunch of hints.

```
find name_of_folder -name "*.flac" -exec script_to_convert {} \;
```

script_to_convert:

filename=$1
   newname=`dirname $filename`/`basename $filename .flac`.mp3
   sox filename newname

I suggest you keep the .flac (backup), as it a lossless compression, in contrast to mp3, which degrades the quality.